# What is the difference between these two date?

Tags: php, date

I have two date:

```
2014-12-01T12:05:59Z //dont know which format
```

And

```
2014-12-01T03:59:00-08:00 //i'll get it from date("c") function in  php (ISO 8601).
```

So, I don't know what is the different in this date's?

And how to convert date in `2014-12-01T12:05:59Z` this formate in php?

**[UPDATE]**
I want to get current timestamps in in `2014-12-01T12:05:59Z` this date formate.

Comment: read this http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: I guess you are trying to save a date generated on the client side on to the database?

Comment: I want to get timestamps in `2014-12-01T12:05:59Z` formate for pass this timestamps to server for use it's API.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

echo gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
```

Check the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). You will get the difference as well.

Comment: This will only work if default timezone is set to `UTC` (or timezone arbitration with +0000 offset). If not, returned datetime will be wrong! Use `gmdate()` instead. And 2nd parameter in `date()` function can be omitted, because `time()` is default, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: @Glavić Is this same output in `gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z')` and `date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z')` where `UTC-8`?

Answer (score 0):

It's the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format and both [time zone variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) are allowed and must be expected. `-08:00` means 8 hours behind UTC, `Z` means UTC and is a shortcut for `+00:00`.

Comment: What should i write code in php for get this format?

Comment: `date( 'c', $iTime )` will give you this format - I don't know why you ask something you already found out yourself.

Comment: You said you want the **current timestamp** in **this format**, meaning you want a Unix timestamp in ISO 8601 format. Do you instead want to parse an ISO 8601 format to a Unix timestamp?

Comment: In `date('c')` there is `+00:00`  in lase of timestamp. But i just want `Z`

Comment: That has been answered (almost) already: `gmdate( 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:s\\Z', $iTime )`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65963/discussion-between-kupendra-and-amigojack).

Answer (score -1):

Both the dates you have mentioned are dates with timezone. The only difference is that the first date has `'z'` at the end which is a `Zone Designator for UTC` and the later date is suffixed with timezone offset, which is generally represented as `"HH:MM"`. Practically, both dates are same and both the representations are correct.

The `'z'` suffixed representation is generally accepted xml standard for timestamp in API payloads.

Looking at your requirements, since your API provider needs the date with `Zone Designator`, they must be calculating time in UTC.
I will suggest changing your timezone to UTC first using

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

and then use this expression to get required timestamp

```
date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', time());
```

This way you are saved from the timezone conflict and you will also be able to send the required date to the API.